# Convert date string to DateTime format

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I have the date string like `03/10/1999` where the format is `dd/MM/yyyy` (pt-BR format).

And I need to convert this date for a SQL-like format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff`.

I tried to use Parse and ParseExact functions, but no success so far. I will let my results below...

---

Using **Parse**

```
var BrazilianDate = "03/10/1999";
var Parse = DateTime.Parse(BrazilianDate, new CultureInfo("pt-BR"));
Console.WriteLine("Parsed date: " + Parse);
```

Output: `Parsed date: 10/3/1999 12:00:00 AM`

No hyphens or milliseconds...

---

Using **ParseExact**

```
var BrazilianDate = "03/10/1999";
var ParseExact = DateTime.ParseExact(BrazilianDate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", new CultureInfo("pt-BR"));
Console.WriteLine(ParseExact);
```

output:

> Run-time exception (line -1): String was not recognized as a valid
>   DateTime.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid
>   DateTime.]    at System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(String s, String
>   format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style)    at
>   System.DateTime.ParseExact(String s, String format, IFormatProvider
>   provider)    at Program.Main()

Comment: Your `ParseExact` pattern is "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff" - that's clearly not the format of the data you're trying to parse.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Simply do _not_ convert to a datetime _string_ for SQL but instead pass as a `DateTime` parameter to your SQL query.

Comment: A `DateTime` value has no inherent format. It is basically an Int64 value counting ticks since DateTime.MinValue. The `(Try)Parse`/`ParseExact` methods expect the format of the string you're trying to get the `DateTime` information **from**. While the `ToString` method of the DateTime expects the format, you want the value to be displayed **to**. If you don't specify the "to"-format, the default format of the culture of the current (UI?) thread is used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to format your output with the correct format string like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Parsed date: " + Parse.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"));
//Parsed date: 1999-10-03 00:00:00.000
```

If you don't specify a format, .NET picks whatever it thinks is the right one (which it often isn't when you're not in the US).

You also need to strictly separate between the `DateTime` value and its representation in `string` form. No matter how you format it, the value itself will stay the same.

Answer (score 2):

The format string you use in the `parse` method represents the format of the input string.

A `DateTime` does not have a display format, in fact it's a numeric value representing the number of ticks since a specific Epoch. 
From [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.8#quick-links-to-remarks-topics):

> Time values are measured in 100-nanosecond units called ticks. A particular date is the number of ticks since 12:00 midnight, January 1, 0001 A.D. (C.E.) in the GregorianCalendar calendar. The number excludes ticks that would be added by leap seconds. For example, a ticks value of 31241376000000000L represents the date Friday, January 01, 0100 12:00:00 midnight.

When parsing strings, I find it's best to either use `ParseExact` or `TryParseExact`. To print our the string representation of the `DateTime` value, use the overload of `ToString` that takes in a `string` that represent the format you want to display.

```
var BrazilianDateString = "03/10/1999";
var DateTimeValue = DateTime.ParseExact(BrazilianDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(DateTimeValue.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

Answer (score -1):

This code is working for me:

```
        DateTime dt = new DateTime();

        string x = "03/10/1999 22:10:10";

        dt = DateTime.Parse(x);

        Console.WriteLine(dt.ToShortDateString());
        Console.WriteLine(dt.ToShortTimeString());

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Console output:

03/10/1999

22:10

Don't use that CultureInfo, DateTime can understand spanish-brazilian dates on its own

Comment: Using `CultureInfo` is actually exactly the right call here. Depending on the current culture, `03/10/1999` might be parsed either as `October 3rd 1999` or `March 10th 1999`.